# update requires a valid updatecommand when passed datarow collection with modified rows

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Am trying to update the access database with the values in the datagrid by the following command:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(Con)
    Dim bsource As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("Config_access")
    Me.DataGridView1.BindingContext(dt).EndCurrentEdit()
    Me.da.Update(dt)
    MsgBox("Table Updated")
End Sub
```

I am facing the error mentioned in the subjectline. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few pieces you have missing. You need a command object and an update command for your data adapter. You'll need to know how to write an update SQL statement. It is suggested you use parameters to identify which row you want to update. Maybe your table has some sort of unique id field (Primary Key)? You can include some of the table information in your question to get feedback on how to do that.

You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand.aspx) to address the command error. If you run into other errors, you may want to repost.